# Custom checkbox in swift 3

Tags: ios, checkbox, swift3, uibutton

am new to swift,

I had two check box buttons on view controller, when click single check box button(Indvidual) it's check and uncheck working fine, but 
my aim is when I check "PICK" checkBox button uncheck the "Drop Check Box"

[image]

if I can select PickUP checkBox  Drop should uncheck 
if select Drop CheckBox PickUP Should uncheck 
but its not happening its selecting Both

[image]

this is my code for single check

```
@IBAction func PushButtonClick(_ sender: UIButton) {

        let buttontag = sender.tag


        if isChecked {
            sender.setImage(UIImage(named:"check1"), for: .normal)
            print("checked")


            isChecked = false
        }
        else {
            sender.setImage( UIImage(named:"uncheck1"), for: .normal)
            isChecked = true
            print("uncheck")

        }
    }

    @IBAction func DropButtonClick(_ sender: UIButton) {


        if isChecked {
            sender.setImage(UIImage(named:"check1"), for: .normal)
            print("checked")
            isChecked = false
        }
        else {
            sender.setImage( UIImage(named:"uncheck1"), for: .normal)
            isChecked = true
            print("uncheck")

        }

    }
```

if one check box check check other check box Is unchecked how to over come this problem........

Comment: your question is not clear

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik when I can click pick button unselect the dropbutton

Comment: if I can click drop dutton un select the pick button

Comment: simple , wait I will update answer

Comment: do you want any one button is selected?right when pickup is select then drop will be deselect

Comment: @NishantBhindi yes Bro

Comment: @raj You cannot control the two checkBoxes using one boolean ('isChecked'). Either use two different boolean for the two buttons or make use of isSelected property of Button.

Comment: @Anuraj how to do Bro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**step-1**

create one button array for store the buttons

```
var buttonscheck = [UIButton]()
```

**step-2**

on page load add the buttons to that array, for e.g

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
   buttonscheck.append(btnPick)
   buttonscheck.append(btnDrop)
}
```

as well as create the common func for both buttons, for e.g

```
 @IBAction func PushButtonClick(_ sender: UIButton) {
```

**step-3**

before assign the check remove the previous selection of your UIbuttons, for e.g

```
 @IBAction func PushButtonClick(_ sender: UIButton) {

    // clear previous selection of your buttons
    for getbutton in buttonscheck {
     getbutton.setImage( UIImage(named:"uncheck1"), for: .normal)
    } 
  // finally set the selected image for your button and it will hold the current button
   sender.setImage(UIImage(named:"check1"), for: .normal)
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can bind both Button's IBAction in one method using Tag you can do it easily

```
@IBAction func radiobtn_Clicked(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    if(sender.tag == 0){ //PickButton's Tag = 0
        btnPick.setImage(UIImage(named: "icon_chkbox_sel"), for: .selected)
        btnPick.isSelected = true
        btnDrop.isSelected = false
    }
    else if(sender.tag == 1){//DropButton's Tag = 1
        btnDrop.setImage(UIImage(named: "icon_chkbox_sel"), for: .selected)
        btnDrop.isSelected = true
        btnPick.isSelected = false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use button isSelected property

`button.setImage(UIImage(named: "check1"), for: .selected)
 button.setImage(UIImage(named: "uncheck1"), for: .normal)`